# Picard group of a cubic hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors, picard-group

Consider the following cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^5$:

$$
X = \{z_0z_3z_5-z_1^2z_5-z_0z_4^2+2z_1z_2z_4-z_2^2z_3 = 0\}\subset\mathbb{P}^5
$$

The singular locus of $X$ is the Veronese surface $V\subset X$. I would like to ask if it is known what is the Picard group of $X\setminus V$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is cyclic, generated by $\mathscr{O}(1)$. Indeed this is true for $X$ by the Lefschetz theorem (SGA2, Exp. XII, Cor. 3.7), and the restriction map $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X\smallsetminus V)  $ is an isomorphism, because the local rings of $X$ are parafactorial by SGA2, Exp. XI, Thm. 3.13).

**Edit:** This is wrong, as pointed out by @F_L  in the comments (thanks!). The mistake is that parafactoriality must be checked at *all* points of $V$, and not only the closed points. The local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X,v}$ at the generic point $v$ of $V$ must be not parafactorial. I leave the answer since I think the error is instructive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is it clear what is the smallest power of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ that is trivial? Do you know if there is an alternative argument not using the fact $X$ is a complete intersection? For instance, using the fact that $X\setminus V$ is an orbit of an algebraic group.

Comment: No power of $\mathscr{O}(1)$ is trivial (Lefschetz gives an isomorphism $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^5)\rightarrow  \operatorname{Pic}(X)$). And yes, you can probably give a proof using that $X\smallsetminus V$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Ok. So $Pic(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and it's generated by the hyperplane section. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I found the Theorem in SGA2 saying that the local rings of $X$ are parafactorial but why does this imply that $Pic(X)\cong Pic(X\setminus V)$?

Comment: This is Proposition 3.3 of SGA 2, Exposé XI.

Comment: I am looking at this arxiv version https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511279.pdf. At page 101 they say that $Pic(X)\rightarrow Pic(X\setminus V)$ is surjective but they do not claim that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am talking about Proposition 3.3, p. 101, same version.

Comment: @ abx. Consider the divisor $D$ in $X$ defined by $\{Z_2Z_3-Z_1Z_4 = Z_1Z_2-Z_0Z_4 = Z_1^2-Z_0Z_3 = 0\}$. This is a cone with vertex $[0:\dots:0:1]$ over a $2$-dimensional cubic scroll $S$ contained in $\{Z_5=0\}$. The restriction of $D$ to $X\setminus V$ is Cartier. If $D = X\cap H$ for some hypersurface $H\subset\mathbb{P}^5$ then $H$ must be a hyperplane. On the other hand, if $H$ is a hyperplane such that $H\cap X = D$ then $H$ must be the hyperplane generated by $S$ which does not contain the vetrtex of $D$. So, it seems that $D$ can not be cut out on $X\setminus V$ by any hypersurface.

Comment: One can cut out $2D$ on $X\setminus V$ intersecting $X$ with a quadric hypersurface. So it seems that there is a $2$-torsion divisor in $\text{Pic}(X\setminus V)$.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to find $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is the following. Note that the cubic $X$ is the symmetric determinantal cubic and it has a resolution of singularities
$$
\tilde{X} = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(S^2\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)).
$$
its explicit form implies that $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, the exceptional divisor of the contraction $\tilde{X} \to X$ is the subvariety
$$
E = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))
$$
and its embedding into $\tilde{X}$ is the relative double Veronese embedding. Finally, it is easy to check that the class of $E$ in $\mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X})$ is equal to
$$
2H + 2h,
$$
where $h$ is the hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $H$ is the relative hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(S^2\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2))$.
Therefore
$$
\mathrm{Pic}(X \setminus V) = \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X} \setminus E) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: Is it immediate to see that $\tilde{X}$ is the projectivization of $S^2\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)$? I can see that that $\tilde{X}$ has a fibration over $\mathbb{P}^2$ with fiber $\mathbb{P}^2$ but not that it is the projectivization of this particular vector bundle.